# How can I add a ipfw forward rule to little snitch?

Tags: mac, network, firewall

I use the following rules to connect to my nginx server on a vagrant machine:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to me 80
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8090 tcp from any to me 443
```

after installing little snitch, it seems to have made ipfw useless and i can't figure out how to apply a forward rule to little snitch?

Comment: little snitch is blocking it ? the incoming traffic !

Comment: no it just seems that it ignores ipfw rules. calling 127.0.0.1:8080 works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ipfw is also removed in Yosemite the solution is to use pf

create a file in /etc/pf.anchors/

e.g. com.myapp

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

NOTE: Add a trailing line break. Otherwise pf will say you have a syntax error.

edit /etc/pf.conf add right after `rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"`:

```
rdr-anchor "myapp"
```

and after `load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"`:

```
load anchor "myap" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.myapp"
```

NOTE: Add a trailing line break. Otherwise pf will say you have a syntax error.

Next, reload the rules into pf by running `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`

Finally, enable pf by running `sudo pfctl -e`

Source: https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/452